# Pusher on Laravel works at my local machine, but not on my server?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, push-notification, pusher

https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-realtime-laravel-apps-with-pusher/

I already implement this workshop using Laravel 5.1 and Pusher package for Laravel : vinkla/pusher. all tutorial works like a charm. But when i push into server it's won't work, only can subscribe the channel, but cannot push to the channel. Error log :

```
     [2016-02-21 14:05:40] local.INFO: Pusher: ->trigger received string channel "notifications". Converting to array.  
    [2016-02-21 14:05:40] local.INFO: Pusher: curl_init( http://api.pusherapp.com:80/apps/181424/events?auth_key=32aea0a14bc90322ecc1&auth_signature=deedcab171279a4bfe9dc835a407e9ae4ed871f91ee3423eeff00313837c8bea&auth_timestamp=1456063540&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=c758199031bf3c1e9e158a1a48de08ff )  
    [2016-02-21 14:05:40] local.INFO: Pusher: trigger POST: {"name":"new-notification","data":"{\"text\":\"ajsfa fasjfasf\"}","channels":["notifications"]}  
    [2016-02-21 14:05:40] local.INFO: Pusher: exec_curl response: Array
    (
        [body] => 
        [status] => 0
    )

    [2016-02-21 14:05:40] local.INFO: Pusher: exec_curl error: Could not resolve host: api.pusherapp.com
```

I think the problem is in here : " Pusher: exec_curl error: Could not resolve host: api.pusherapp.com " i already try some trick, but still doesn't work.

Thankyou in advance (:

Comment: Can you access api.pusherapp.com from your server at all (i.e. try using cURL outside of Laravel to access that page)?

Comment: I can access it, with command : curl api.pusherapp.com 
and returned : Pusher Api

Comment: Did you run that from the same server that your Laravel app is running from? If it works when you run it manually, then this problem does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, i run that command from same server with my Laravel app. i got stressed about that ) :

Answer (score 0):

Pusher is known to have timezone issues. Did you try the following?

If your server is running Ubuntu:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

If your server is running CentOS:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739664/4178110

Comment: how about windows 10?? because my live server is windows 10

Answer (score 0):

disable the TLS: `"useTLS"    => false`

```
'auth_key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
'options' => [
     "cluster"   => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
     "encrypted" => true,
     "useTLS"    => false, //disable this
 ],
```

Comment: Incase someone reaches here, domain `pusherapp` could not be resolved. Rather it's become `api-cluster.pusher.com`

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Push notification works fine on my local but on server it did not work. so after debuging I found that `cloudflare` cache the old files. so I run `npm run dev` and purge cache on `cloudflare`. push notifications works fine.
you can also enable debugger if this did not help you

> Pusher.logToConsole = true;