# Laravel: Pusher events do not broadcast from within eloquent's event listener

Tags: php, laravel, events, pusher

I'm having issues doing event broadcasting using Pusher from within an Eloquent event listener. My event are being fired and sent out from Laravel controller perfectly. However, it seems that the broadcasts are not actually reaching pusher when I trigger them from within my Eloquent event listener.

The `boot` method of my `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` contains:

```
MyModel::saving(function($record){
    doSomeStuf();

    // trigger event
    $pusher = \App::make('pusher');
    $channel = $record->username;
    $pusher->trigger($channel, 'status-changed', $record);

    doSomeOtherStuf();

    return true;
});
```

The js file that subscribes to the event has no problem listening to the event when the same code is placed in a controller.

Also note that `doSomeStuf()` and `doSomeOtherStuf()` are executed quite fine and no exception is thrown.

Comment: your dates or other information of server and local machines might not being synchronized. you need to look at this.
http://www.ntp.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a date synchronization issue.

My local server is an Ubuntu machine while my live server is running on CentOS. Running the following commands solved the problem:

Ubuntu:

`sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`

CentOS:

`sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

Comment: how about windows 10?